# How should I resolve a "ld: library not found for -liconv" error when running "cargo build"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, iconv

After installing Rust and Cargo via the following command...

```bash
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

I ran `cargo build` on a tiny "Hello World" Rust project and got the following error:

```
= note: ld: library not found for -liconv
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `hello_world` due to previous error
```

I've tried `rustup self uninstall` then installing Rust and Cargo via `brew`, but I get the same error when attempting to build.

I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.6.4.

Comment: Is `iconv`/`libiconv` installed? It's the standard library for handling non-ASCII text encoding, and without it, most stuff that handles non-ASCII text is going to have issues.

Comment: I have `iconv` installed, but not `libiconv`.

Comment: The error is basically saying "What you're building requires libiconv, `ld` (the library loader) can't find it", so the solution is either: 1) Install `libiconv` if it's missing, and/or 2) Fix the environment (setting stuff like `LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_RUN_PATH`, or providing switches with equivalent effect to the compiler) to find the `libiconv` that's already installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First step is to install `libiconv` via Homebrew:

```sh
brew install libiconv
```

Notice that the output is saying something weird:

```
==> Caveats
libiconv is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have libiconv first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libiconv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find libiconv you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libiconv/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libiconv/include"
```

I haven't been able to piece together a complete explanation, but it is something to do with `libiconv` being provided by MacOS in a version that has the wrong symbols. On my system `libiconv` can't be found (is it a M1 thing?); nevertheless, brew refuses to step on the OSes' toes, which seems a reasonable decision.

These variables do not apply to `cargo` however.

The best way to solve the problem (that I found) is to modify your `LIBRARY_PATH` variable to provide path to iconv. You might have already had to modify your `LIBRARY_PATH` (see e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40704/homebrew-installed-libraries-how-do-i-use-them).

What I did was to add the following line to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix)/lib:$(brew --prefix)/opt/libiconv/lib
```

Afterwards `libiconv` is detected correctly.

Comment: alternatively you can use a bit modified command:
`$(brew --prefix libiconv)/lib`

Comment: cool! can't try it out because i don't have a Mac anymore. if someone confirms, feel free to edit it into the answer

Answer (score 5):

If you've installed GNU gcc, or really any not-Apple C compiler it can cause this issue.

In addition to doing what the other answer recommends (`brew install libiconv`) also check and see if your `cc` command is Apple clang or a version of gcc. You can do this with `which -a cc`.

You can basically force `cc` to be the apple clang version by running:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin/:$PATH"
```

Then rust should work

Comment: Any clues how to install `cc`? Should it be Clang or GCC? What command to use? Brew? System Preferences?

Comment: Install xcode or the xcode command line tools. It should include clang and cc. It sounds like you've probably done that (for brew), so if you're still missing cc something else is probably wrong. CC can be clang or gcc depending on what you're doing, but most things will probably expect it to be the apple clang.